# Identify X libs during installation from source without sudo

Tags: sudo, install-from-source

I am trying to install a program ([HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk)) from source, but after `./configure` (which doesn't give errors), `make all` complains that `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11`. This is a [well-known problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2013496) which supposedly can be solved via `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0 /usr/lib32/libX11.so`. However, we would prefer not using `sudo`. Is there a way to do this locally?

xorg-dev et al. are installed.
(Sadly, HTK is only semi-free so it is not found in any repos.)

Answer (score 2):

If xorg-dev is installed, you should have a file named /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so (or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so on 64-bit, but HTK compiles in 32-bit even on 64-bit plateform, unless you patch it, so it's the i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so that is used anyway)

then you can use the option `--x-libraries` of `./configure`

```
./configure --x-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

plus any other option for `./configure` that you need (see `./configure --help` for more options and informations about options)

Alternatively, this could work:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0 ~/lib/libX11.so
```

if it's not enough rerun `./configure` using the option `--x-libraries`

```
./configure --x-libraries=~/lib
```

As an *anecdotal* side note, I just downloaded htk-3.4.1 and `./configure && make` worked without problem. I have libX11.so in both /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so but no symlink in /usr/lib32. I use gcc 4.6.3, and I'm on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, but HTK compiled with `-m32` option of gcc (i.e. compile in 32-bit mode)

`./configure` said:

> checking for main in -lX11... yes.

and `file HTKTools/HInit` returned:

> HTKTools/HInit: ELF 32-bit LSB executable